# Record should only be loaded to target on a scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-update

I have two tables a stage table and a target table. I want my target table to hold valid CustomerScore values. Currently, we insert into staging and load to our target table. We do not want to load invalid values(-8.0000). However, if there is a customerNumber with a valid value in our target table we would like to decommission numbers by giving it a customerScore of (-8.0000). This should be the only time this value makes it into the target table, so a record for that CustomerNumber has to already be in the target for this to update that record currently in the target table. My create statement is below

```
CREATE TABLE stg.CustomerAppreciation (
    CustomerId INT identity(1, 1)
    ,CustomerNumber VARCHAR(50)
    ,CustomerScore DECIMAL(5, 4)
    );

CREATE TABLE ods.CustomerAppreciation (
    CustomerId INT identity(1, 1)
    ,CustomerNumber VARCHAR(50)
    ,CustomerScore DECIMAL(5, 4)
    );
```

Currently, my target table has two records, each value below belongs to my create table fields.

```
1     123      0.8468
2     143      1.0342
```

Now say we want to decommission CustomerID = 2 because there is a record been inserted into staging as

```
3     143      -8.0000
```

The target table should now be updated on this CustomerNumber. Making my target table look like:

```
1     123      0.8468
2     143      -8.0000
```

This should be the only time we allow -8.0000 into the table when a CustomerNumber already exists. If a customerNumber does not exists in the target table and for some reason -8.0000 is seen in staging it should not be allowed in. How would I write an update query that updates a record in my target table only if that scenario exists and prevents -8.0000 from coming in if it does not exist?

Comment: When the record to decommission `CustomerNumber = 143` comes into staging, will the previous records for that `CustomerNumber` still be in the staging table? Will a `CustomerNumber` ever appear twice in the staging table during a single run of the data import?

Comment: You tagged SSIS, this is done via lookup object in the data flow where one path has "matches" and leads to an update and one path is "no match" and leads to an insert. However, you only want to deal with the update side of things and just let the "no match" die in the lookup

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the staging table only contains one row per customer number (if not, group it to show the highest customer Id), you can use a merge to perform this function. Without checking exact syntax, something like this:

```
MERGE ods.CustomerAppreciation AS Target
USING (SELECT * FROM stg.CustomerAppreciation WHERE CustomerScore >= 0) AS Source   ON Target.CustomerNumber = Source.CustomerNumber
WHEN MATCHED
    -- choose your match criteria here
    --AND Source.CustomerId > Target.CustomerId 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT Target.* INTERSECT SELECT Source.*)
THEN UPDATE
    SET Target.CustomerScore = Source.CustomerScore;
```

Comment: Is a merge the only solution to achieving this? I want it to prevent loading the invalid value if there is no CustomerNumber in the target table with a valid number that matches the staging. but if there is one that matches I want it to update that one setting it equal as you did in the merge

Comment: There are many ways to skin this particular cat, but most are functionally equivalent. Using the `Where CustomerScore >= 0` filter in the source table should stop invalid values from being loaded into the target table. Since there is no `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target` clause, you will not load values at all that do not exist in the Target already. You could add that clause with another suitable `and...` condition. If this gets too complex, you could expand it all out into several `IF [Condition] INSERT INTO Target` commands, if that seems easier.

Comment: I would say the first step is to get only the data you want in the source table, even if that means using a subselect joining the staging and target tables (use a left join to the target table). You should then be able to merge from that with as many criteria as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand the specifics but here is some syntax that should help to at least get you started ...

```
BEGIN;
 MERGE ods.CustomerAppreciation AS X  
 USING (SELECT CustomerNumber,CustomerScore FROM stg.CustomerAppreciation) AS Y (CustomerNumber,CustomerScore)  
 ON (X.CustomerNumber = Y.CustomerNumber)  
 WHEN MATCHED /*AND Y.CustomerNumber = '-8.0000'*/ THEN
 UPDATE SET CustomerScore = Y.CustomerScore  
 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY X /*AND Y.CustomerNumber = '-8.0000'*/ THEN  
 INSERT (CustomerNumber,CustomerScore)  
 VALUES (Y.CustomerNumber,Y.CustomerScore)  
 OUTPUT $action, inserted.* INTO #MyTempTable;  
END;
```